# How can I share certain records of a custom object with my community's guest users?

Tags: community, sharing, roles, guest-user, sharing-rule

I am using a criteria-based sharing rule to share my custom object with internal users and registered users of my Community.  I would now like to add a rule to share with guest users of the Community.  I've researched in the [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_data_set_categories.htm&language=en_US), but given that Guest users don't have a role, I can't seem to use a Sharing Rule for this purpose.

Is there another approach I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use criteria based sharing for this situation. You'll want to change the OWD and FLS for External Users on your Custom Object, enabling at least read only access to the Custom Object for your Guest User Profile.

If this is a Customer Portal, you can create Sharing Groups to share specific records with if you only want to share certain ones. Also, the Guest User Profile is not the correct profile to use with registered Customer Community Users.